# Tex code in IEEE HTML format

Tags: equations, ieee-style

In IEEE , many recent journals are being offered in HTML format as well. One advantage it has the pdf version is that the tex code is easily available and big equations can be directly taken from the tex source. A snapshot is shared below. But when I'm trying to use the as is code given in sample 1 below, in a tex file , it gives the below error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.46         $$\eqalignno
{
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Similar error when using the sample 2 given below

Code :
Sample 1
    `$$\eqalignno{{\mbi x}(t + 1) = &\, {\mbi\Phi} (t){\mbi x}(t) + {\mbi{\mbi 
    \Gamma}} (t){\mbi w}(t)&{\hbox{(1)}} \cr {\mmb z}(t) =&\, {\mbi H}(t)
    {\mbi x}(t) + {\mbi \nu}(t)&{\hbox{(2)}}}$$`
Sample 2
    `$$\displaylines{{\mbi y}(t) = \xi_1 (t){\mmb z}(t) + \xi _2 (t){\mmb z}(t - 
    1) + \xi _3 (t){\mbi y}(t - 1)\hfill\cr\hfill + (1 - \xi _1 (t) - \xi _2 (t) 
    - \xi _3 (t)){\mbi \nu}(t).\quad{\hbox{(6)}}}$$`

Please help me in fixing this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\equalignno` is plain TeX so not defined in LaTeX. If you are using plain tex it should work.

```
\font\bolditalmath=cmmib10 
\newfam\zz
\textfont\zz=\bolditalmath
\def\mbi{\fam\zz}
\let\mmb=\mbi %??
Test:
$$\eqalignno{{\mbi x}(t + 1) = &\, {\mbi\Phi} (t){\mbi x}(t) + {\mbi{\mbi 
    \Gamma}} (t){\mbi w}(t)&{\hbox{(1)}} \cr {\mmb z}(t) =&\, {\mbi H}(t)
    {\mbi x}(t) + {\mbi \nu}(t)&{\hbox{(2)}}}$$

\bye
```

Comment: I use texlive distribution with texmaker as the editor. I execute in pdflatex. Can you explain me how to run in plain tex @David

Comment: @naiveBayes no idea about texmaker, but on the commandline just type `pdftex filename` instead of `pdflatex filename` I just put a complete plain tex document into the answer

Comment: Thanks @David.. Its working as expected. Is it possible that I can define a specific syntax for eqalignno and execute in LaTex ?

Comment: @naiveBayes you could use `\usepackage{plain}` and `\begin{plain}..\end{plain}` (a truely ancient package of mine:-)